# Having trouble to download a doc file that it's generated from PHP code

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to download a doc file when I click on button.
Also, this doc file is generated from a php code.

I have the following `HTML`, `jQuery` and `PHP` code but without success:

```
<li><a href="" id="docFormat">DOC</a></li>

<script>
$('#docFormat').on('click', function(event) {
    '<?php' +  
        'header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");' + 
        'header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TablaSectores.doc");' +  
        'echo "<table id="sectoresTable"><thead><tr><th><b>#</b></th><th><b>Numero</b></th><th><b>Nombre</b></th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>";' + 
    '?>'
});
</script>
```

When I click on the button, it isn't download nothing. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: your mixing php and js in a way that can never work. also you some how think some html makes a valid word "doc" file just because you give it a file-name *.doc

Comment: PHP code *runs on the server*, not in the browser. You should create a PHP file on your server, such as `generatedoc.php`, and then link to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you started new to programming ...

you must learn what is the different of php (serversided) and javascript(clientsided)... so the full system how it works

please read or watch tuts where someone defining client and seversided languages and webserver functionality... also the functionality of php and javascript
good luck

and you use Jquery thats not normal javascript ... jquery is an extension look for tuts online -> ("$('#docFormat').on('click', function(event) {")
for jquery you need to bind the extension .. there are free hosts online like google who hosting the extensions but not needed for your script :)

your code :
first create an php file called download.php and paste this code:
this code will now opened and start the download..

download.php

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TablaSectores.doc");
?>
```

this code is to open the download.php via click .. you must open a the downlaod.php if you will download the file so just use html :)

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="download.php">DOC</a>
</body>
</html>
```

learn more about this and you will start to understand how it works

have a nice start and i wish you luck .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing things up. The php code you're nesting in the function call, is being parsed when the page is sent to the browser, so long before anyone can click on the button.

You need to set up a route (e.g. /doc/download.php), where you place the PHP code. Then replace the body of your jQuery function with an ajax call.